# Android: Keep MediaPlayer running during Activity screen orientation update

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation, android-mediaplayer

I use a MediaPlayer to play an MP3. Currently I disabled screen orientation changes by using

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in the manifest. I do want to support landscape mode now - i.e. removed those tags - but have the problem that during the destroy/create cycle the player gets stopped and then restarted. This is okay and I actually do this even manually in `onPause()` to stop the player when the activity goes in the background.

To keep it running during orientation changes now, I tried making it static (and using the Application Context to create it once). Of course, when I remove the `player.stop()` in `onPause()` now, it does what I want - well, *until* the Activity goes in the background.

So, two questions:

- How can I determine if the Activity will be recreated directly after the call to `onStop()`
- Or: How can I keep the `MediaPlayer` running during that cycle, yet stop it when the App goes in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) callback to handle some of this logic?

Comment: It doesn't get called due to the removed `android:configChanges` in the manifest.

Comment: If you want to differentiate between when you just change configurations and when you actually stop, I don't know of any other way of doing it other than using onConfigurationChanged(). Which I guess means you'll have to keep the `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest :\

Comment: Ouch. Simply adding it again did it already; Seems the default implementation does indeed handle the layout changes. Thanks a million! :)

Comment: @Kurtis It's not true that you can't determine configuration changes reliably; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question how you can reliably determine whether your Activity is destroyed due to a configuration change, see my answer here: [How to save/restore(update) ref to the dialog during screen rotation?(I need ref in onCreate method of activity.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374093/how-to-save-restoreupdate-ref-to-the-dialog-during-screen-rotationi-need-ref/14374343#14374343)

With this, the answer to your second question should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `MediaPlayer` in different Thread.

You can add to this thread a more complex API to which you can call from `onCreate`/`onStop`/`on*`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fragments (and you should :P), then calling `setRetainInstance(true)` inside your fragments onCreate() call will make this problem go completely go away.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31466602/994021

It is a POC I've created for this purpose. Tired of solving this issue over and over again for different projects. I hope it helps.

I really recommend to switch to a third party player like ExoPlayer from google guys: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: i m using ExoPlayer but how will i  handle this ?

Comment: @Erum you will have to use the flag <code>android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"</code> in your activity.

Comment: @Gasper de Elias i already did this but there is something other issue my layout i not adjusting programatically once i change orientation ?