# How to have Activity continue streaming video when orientation is changed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Keep MediaPlayer running during Activity screen orientation update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014603/android-keep-mediaplayer-running-during-activity-screen-orientation-update)

Android's YouTube app has some features:

When the screen of the device is in portrait and you watch a video and change the orientation of the screen to landscape, the video is shown full screen and the list of related videos disappears. It continues playing without restarting or restreaming.

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

The problems are:

- When I create my layout XML files as "layout" and "layout-land", my Activity is destroyed when going from portrait to landscape. I have to restream the video.
- If I set `Androidmanifest.xml` to use `android:configChanges="orientation"`, then the Activity is not destroyed, but the layout does not change.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @slhck How can i change my layout when change from portrait to landscape?

Comment: @slhck But the answer there is not exactly satisfactory I'd say.

Comment: @ClassStacker Which doesn't make it less of a duplicate question, unfortunately. You could place a bounty on it, for example. tungdx, I don't know—you'd have to restart the Activity to redraw the layout. Maybe you can selectively disable some elements of the layout you don't need?

Comment: @slhck You _do_ have a point there ;)

Comment: @tungdx  how u resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a Thread for the media player (well, you'll already have one). Your activity can reliably determine whether it is destroyed due to a configuration change, see my answer here: [How to save/restore(update) ref to the dialog during screen rotation?(I need ref in onCreate method of activity.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374093/how-to-save-restoreupdate-ref-to-the-dialog-during-screen-rotationi-need-ref/14374343#14374343)

So it's not bad that your Activity is re-created; all you need to do is re-attach the player to it.

Comment: I understand your idea. I do follow it but it has a problem, when i rotate device, layout change to layout-land and mediaplyer has continue running, but I can hear sound but i can't see video. How could i fix it? Here my code: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4mVLTWlnazzUmpVVndOZDJaTTA/edit

Comment: I see you have successfully followed the schematic approach. However, you have not attached the MediaPlayer to your newly created Activity. You'll have to call `setSurface()` on the already existing `MediaPlayer` object after the context change.

Comment: @tungdx I've taken a second look at your code. One might expect this to work already. Have the logs provided any insight?

Comment: Could you show me how i can set new setSurface() on the already existing MediaPlayer? and my english is bad, I don't understand your question "Have the logs provided any insight?".

Comment: @tungdx Can you update your question with the log output you get when you rotate the device and notify me when you have done it?

Comment: This is my logcat from my application. Before rotate: http://i1080.photobucket.com/albums/j321/xuantunga2/before_rotate_zps28c659a1.png and after rotate: http://i1080.photobucket.com/albums/j321/xuantunga2/after_rotate_zps76146251.png .

Comment: @tungdx Thank you for the logs. You can try two things. 1) Disable hardware acceleration in the player settings. 2) If you play a local file, it would be better to `getCurrentPosition()`, then `stop()` before the activity is destroyed, then create the surface when the activity is again created, then call `prepareAsync()`, `seekTo()` and `start()`.

Comment: I play a video streaming so it's not good to call prepareAsync() again. Help me, please!

Comment: @tungdx Have you tried to disable hardware acceleration in the media player (manually)? Which Android versions du you test this with?

Comment: @ClassStacker  can u pls help me i m facing same issue  in mediaplayer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624025/mediaplayer-object-getting-null-after-orientation-change

Answer (score 0):

Add android:configChanges="orientation" in you AndroidManifest file;

Add:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

In your Video activity;

Comment: Wamasa: You do not understand my objective. Anyway, thank you!