# How can I save media player state?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on a music player and everything is fine the play, stop, and pause buttons.
My problem is that whenever a song is playing and I press the back button and reopen the app the buttons won't work with the current song.

This happens as well when I change the orientation. Is there a way I can save the state of the media player and then obtain the state so that I can stop the song that is being played?

Comment: you can save the where the song stopped , using preferences or Bundle to save the state and restart the media player again from where it stopped 
take look on this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917994/how-to-play-audio-continuously-while-orientation-in-android

Comment: thanks for the orientation part but now my question would be how to work around when the app quits because whenever I reopen the app the stop button wont work with the current song. thanks for the help guys...

Comment: when you quite from app using shared Preferences to save the state

Comment: ok thank a lot am gonna work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use

```
.getCurrentPosition()
```

to get how many milliseconds into thew song you are, then use

```
.seekTo(int milliseconds)
```

upon resuming or an orientation change, to get to the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SeekTo method. 
[Seek To](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29)

Then add:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
    out.putInt(PLAY_TIME, mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
}
```

And later in the OnCreate, you just need to check something like this:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(PLAY_TIME)) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getInt(PLAY_TIME, 0));
    }
```

Hope this helps